# Excel conditional formatting: contains one string but not another

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

In an Excel column that I've selected, I would like to apply conditional formatting to any cells that contain the string "US-" *except* if they contain the string "US-D". Based on [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/conditional-formatting-highlight-cells-that-dont/2a40da86-c443-41e1-9b28-2c6612e916d7), here how to exclude "US-D",

```
=LEFT(E2,3)<>"US-D"
```

But how to also *include* entries that have "US-" such as US-1 or US-2? Also, what does ",3" means in the formula above, which I copied from the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AND(LEFT(E2,4)<>"US-D, LEFT(E2,3)="US-")
```

LEFT(x,y) takes the first y characters from x.